# Why can't I substitute a value in a merged dataframe?

Tags: r, class, dataframe, types, merge

I have two `dataframes` as follows:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "Source    Signal  Target
A   no  B
B   yes C
C   no  D
D   no  A
E   yes F
F   yes G
G   no  E", header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = "Source    Signal  Target
A   no  B
B   yes C
E   yes F
F   yes G", header = T)
```

I merged `df1` and `df2`: `interactions <- merge(df1, df2)` and then I am trying to `match` each `Source` and `Target` with `df3`.

```
df3 <- read.table(text = "Symbol    ID  Name
A   11  LetterA
C   13  LetterC
D   14  LetterD
F   16  LetterF
G   17  LetterG", header = T)
```

And I get the following output:

```
Source
     Symbol   ID    Name
1         A   11    LetterA
NA     <NA>   NA    <NA>
NA.1   <NA>   NA    <NA>
4         F   16    LetterF
```

*So I want to `replace` the `NA` with the "original" input displayed in `df2` and obtain an output as follows:*

```
Symbol  ID   Name
  A     11   LetterA
  B     NA   B
  E     NA   E
  F     16   LetterF
```

I tried with:

```
Source <- df3[match(interactions$Source, df3$Symbol),-4]
my.na <- is.na(Source$Name)
Source$Name[my.na] <- interactions$Source[my.na]
Source$Symbol[my.na] <- interactions$Source[my.na]
```

But I get numbers instead of characters. Is there something I am missing?
Is it possible to substitute a merged value without using any library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that by default, `read.table` converts strings into factors which are stored as integers which map to a lookup table. So when you try to inset them into `Source`, what it actually inserts is the integer value for that factor. You can get around this by adding the argument: `stringsAsFactors = F` to your `read.table` calls, so that the data there is kept as strings. Now, when you use match to insert the values into `Source` it will insert the strings, not the factor numbers.

If you're still having problems, you may also need to convert the variables in `Source` to character instead of factor. You can do this:

```
# Base R:
Source$Symbol <- as.character(Source$Symbol)
Source$Name <- as.character(Source$Name)

# Dplyr:
library(dplyr)
Source <- Source %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)
```

Comment: Applied your solution and it was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem! I've wasted so much time dealing with unwanted string <-> factor conversions so I'm happy to help!